# How to switch from Twitter API single account use to multiaccount use, keeping it still a private app?

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth

I've made an app that posts to a Twitter account of mine. Currently I have hard-coded into the system the consumer key, consumer secret, access token key and access token secret.

Now I would like to use this app for two accounts and perhaps later even more. Which values have to be changed to make the same app post into the other account and how to get the values? I can see none of them in dev.twitter.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [python-twitter](https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) package is probably going to be what you want here.

the way you should set this up is in settings.py put

```
TWITTER_ACCOUNTS = {
    'public': {
        'consumer_key':        'PUT_C_KEY_HERE',
        'consumer_secret':     'PUT_C_SEC_HERE',
        'access_token_key':    'PUT_A_KEY_HERE',
        'access_token_secret': 'PUT_A_SEC_HERE',
     },
     'personal': {
        'consumer_key':        'PUT_C_KEY_HERE',
        'consumer_secret':     'PUT_C_SEC_HERE',
        'access_token_key':    'PUT_A_KEY_HERE',
        'access_token_secret': 'PUT_A_SEC_HERE',
     },
}
```

from twitter api page:

> For applications with single-user use cases, we now offer the ability to issue an access token for your own account (and your own applications). You can generate these keys from your application details pages.

go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps to get your keys

Then in your code when doing your initialisation, (e.g. for personal account) put

```
import twitter
from django.conf import settings

account = settings.TWITTER_ACCOUNTS['personal']
api = twitter.Api(**account)  # <----This will inject your account settings as keyword args
status = api.PostUpdate('I love python-twitter!')
```

Hope this helps you.

EDIT:
To register your second account with the application, Follow these instructions from Step 3: http://jeffmiller.github.com/2010/05/31/twitter-from-the-command-line-in-python-using-oauth

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but it seems a bit redundant to register an application in Twitter for each account... If everyone is doing this, do they not run out of unique application names? :P Anyways, huge thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: you don't need to register two applications. just register one for your site, then register both acounts with the application

Comment: The tutorial Step 3 was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!